# Duration as timestamp in JSON output

Tags: json, node.js

Api call returns the below JSON object:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "distance": "482 km",
    "duration": "8 hours 46 mins"
}
```

Now I need this "duration" to be converted and sent as timestamp in this format - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
How to go about it?

Comment: you want the output in this format "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S"?

Comment: yeah so in my example it would be - **"P8H46M"** OR should it be - **"PT8H46M"**

Comment: **'P'+s.replace('hours','H').replace('mins','M').replace(/\s/g,'');** you can add more condition like day month year.

Comment: yeah that one works. Thanks.

Comment: In this **replace('hours','H')** how do I match for both 'hours' and 'hour' ?

Comment: I use  **'P'+duration.replace(/\hour+(s?)/i,'H').replace(/\day+(s?)/i,'D').replace('mins','M').replace(/\s/g,'');**
it matches both hours and hour and replaces it with 'H" but it is not matching both 'days' and 'day' and not replacing with 'D'. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Moment.js* which has support to convert the date to [ISO 8601](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-iso-string/) string.

All you have to do is extract hours and minutes from the string.

```js
let d = '8 hours 46 mins'.split(' ')
let result = moment.duration(`${d[0]}:${d[2]}`, 'H:M').toISOString()
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But sometimes the duration would have days too like:
**var d = "2 days 1 hour 40 mins"**
then how does this work @TGrif

Comment: @LaxmiSathy Not a big deal, just change the expected format to add the days. But if the string isn't a regular pattern, you'll have to implement your own specific logic accordingly.